# I want to split my web app into 2 parts using react router. I am using a router inside of one of the previously mentioned routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
/src
|-- /components
|   |-- /signin
|       |-- SignIn.js
|       |-- /home
|           |-- Home.js
|
|           |-- /dashboard
|               |-- Dashboard.js
|    |-- /assignee
|-- /App.js
|-- /index.js
```

As you can see i want to split into 2 parts(signin(adimin part), assignee(user part)).
I am using router for signin and assignee
Also I want to use router for home page, to display dashboard and other pages. How do I make it possible

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="maindiv">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<SignIn />} />
          <Route path="/assignment" element={<AssigneePage />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container className="content">
        <div className="side-nav">
          <Nav />
        </div>
        <div className="main-content">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="/review" element={<Review />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Home` is stacked inside Signup

When I try `"http://localhost:3000/dashboard"` it gives me this error:

> history.ts:501 No routes matched location "/dashboard"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Signin` component, rendered on `"/signin"` renders ***descendent*** routes, e.g. `Signin` renders another `Routes` and set of `Route` components, then the parent route should specify a trailing wildcard `"*"` matcher, or splat, so that all descendent routes can be matched and rendered.

Given your code/route structure

```
/src
|-- /components
|   |-- /signin
|       |-- SignIn.js
|       |-- /home
|           |-- Home.js
|
|           |-- /dashboard
|               |-- Dashboard.js
|    |-- /assignee
|-- /App.js
|-- /index.js
```

Hopefully I've understood correctly your routing organization.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="maindiv">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/*" element={<SignIn />} />
          <Route path="/assignment" element={<AssigneePage />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Since `Home` also renders descendent routes, its parent route in `Signin` also needs to append the wildcard matcher.

```
const SignIn = () => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/home/*"     // <-- "/signin/home"
        element={<Home />}
      />
    </Routes>
    ...
  );
}
```

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container className="content">
        <div className="side-nav">
          <Nav />
        </div>
        <div className="main-content">
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/dashboard"       // <-- "/signin/home/dashboard"
              element={<Dashboard />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/review"          // <-- "/signin/home/review"
              element={<Review />}
            />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See [route splats](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats) for more information.